# Cannot connect to RabbitMq from an Asp.Net application

Tags: windows, iis-7, rabbitmq, windows-server-2012, application-pool

I have a asp.net mvc application that interacts with RabbitMq. Everything works great locally.

However, on our deployment server it cannot connect

```
DEBUG|MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqConnectionCache|Connecting: muyuser@localhost:5672/|
ERROR|MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqReceiveTransport|RabbitMQ connection failed: Connect failed: muyuser@localhost:5672/|
```

What I'm able to gather is this

- In order to connect to RabbitMq you need a valid `.erlang.cookie` in (on windows) your User root
- As best I can tell, this cookie is created when you install rabbitmq
- In development we're using localdb which runs as the developer's user (which has this cookie)
- In production the application runs off of IIS which uses the application pool and the built-in `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account. Which doesn't have a User folder for the `.erlang.cookie` file to live in.

So the question becomes...what now? How is this intended to work?

Obviously we could create a dedicated user for the web application but our system administrator is understandably *very* reluctant to do this.

Another clue, is that when I tried to RDP, log in as myself and connect to rabbit I found that I could not. After troubleshooting I discovered that my cookie didn't match up with that of others who could! I replaced it with the one from `c:\windows\.erlang.cookie` and could then connect from cli. It seems possible like there *is* a cookie installed **somewhere** for the applicationpoolidentity but it is an incorrect cookie. What is the location where it would go?

Comment: Erlang requires the cookie to start rabbitmq - this is not required to connect to the broker from a client, however. Could you clarify how erlang/rabbitmq is being started?  Also clarify which client you are using.

Comment: @theMayer rabbitmq is being started as a windows service (the standard way that it installs). I am connecting using [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) which uses [RabbitMQ.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client/) library under the hood.

Comment: Also @theMayer I'm not sure how "erlang requires the cookie to start rabbitmq" squares with my experience. When I had the wrong cookie in my user folder rabbit mq was already running and a coworker could connect to it yet I could not. Updating my `.erlang.cookie` allowed me to connect

Comment: Connecting to the broker via the AMQP protocol does not require you to even be on the same machine - the cookie is specific to using rabbitmqctl and other command line tools - so something else must be going on.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question because the error at the top is an AMQP connection error, and your troubleshooting steps talk about erlang cookie, which has nothing at all to do with connecting to the broker via 5672.

Answer (score 1):

Erlang cookies are used for internode communication, whether it is for clustering RabbitMQ or for contacting RabbitMQ via the command line using `rabbitmqctl`.

If you have problems with an AMQP connection, then the erlang cookie **has nothing to do here**.

Take a look at access control https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html to see if your user is properly configured.

At the same time check the server logs to see why the connection is refused.

Comment: Yeah, the logs weren't being populated either. Eventually we figured out that we were having issues due to (of course) permissions. The cookie was an educated guess at what was involved.